# Changing the font for braces

Tags: fonts, xetex, braces

I managed to successfully hack mathspec to use parentheses `()` and brackets `[]` from the specified font via e.g.

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{]}{\mathord}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`]}
```

Obviously, I'd like to do the same thing with braces `{}`, but `\DeclareMathSymbol{\{}...` causes XeLaTeX to throw the following error:

```
! Latex Error: Command '\{' already defined.
```

I was half-expecting this to happen all along to be honest. Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem? (I.e. what font are you trying to use?  Does it provide large math delimiters?)  I have tried to answer some of your question in lieu of this information.

Comment: @mforbes Sorry, I guess I could've been clearer with my question. No, the font doesn't provide large delimiters which is why I thought I shouldn't use `\DeclareMathDelimiter`. I'm just looking to replace the basic-sized ones. Relevant code: `\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathfont(Digits)[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Optima nova LT Pro}` I've hacked mathspec.sty itself to include brackets as "Digits".

Comment: If you really want to use ``\DeclareMathSymbol``, you can always just ``\let\lbrace\relax``, but I still think you should use ``\DeclareMathDelimiter``: LaTeX needs to know what to do in the case of delimiters: maybe fallback to Euler?  I must admit I am having difficulty doing that though.  ``\DeclareMathDelimiter`` will automatically set the symbol too.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to modify the delimiters, you should use `\DeclareMathDelimiter` instead of `\DeclaraMathSymbol` so that you can specify both the small and large symbols.

Here is a simple example that changes the left brace to a left parenthesis:

```
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrace}{\mathopen}{operators}{"28}
                                         {largesymbols}{"00}
```

You will need to figure out the slots that contain the appropriate small and large version of the symbol in your desired font if it does not follow a standard encoding.

### References

- [LaTeX2e font guide](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/fntguide.pdf): Look for `\DeclareMathDelimiter`.

Comment: How do I find the correct slots?

Comment: @HenriMenke The only way I know is either to look in a ``*.sty`` file (see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130622/how-to-find-slot-of-a-character)) or to just try cycling though the characters to see what they look like.