# How to find slot of a character

Tags: symbols

Following this "manual":
[Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font)
I try to extract the `\rightsquigarrow` character from the standard `ams` package, since I'm overwriting it with `mathds`. But I don't know how to find the slot number. Trial and error might take too long. Is there a file I can look it up in?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmmm, to me it seems, `dsfont` (which provides `\mathds`) does not overwrite `\rightsquigarrow`.

Comment: Oh then I guess its the `mathabx` package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can look it up in `amssymb.sty`.
`\rightsquigarrow`is defined as:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rightsquigarrow}  {\mathrel}{AMSa}{"20}
```

In general the `*.sty` files for the fonts are a good starting point to find out the slot of defined symbols.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I defined it like that in a newcommand and it perfectly works for me.